# Unable to make an outgoing call after calling *31# on Moto G

Tags: calls, dialer-codes

I have a Moto G (1st generation) mobile bought in India. When I tried to make my Caller ID hidden from [this wikiHow article](https://www.wikihow.com/Make-Your-Mobile-Phone-Number-Appear-As-a-Private-Number), I called `*31#` and after that, I couldn't make a call to anyone.

Then I tried and miraculously I could make a call by adding a prefix of `*31#` to any number.

Please help me out fixing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried solutions from [GSM Feature Codes](https://www.geckobeach.com/cellular/secrets/gsmcodes.php) but no help.

Called Motorola Customer Care and they told me to Factory Reset. I did it after backing up my data and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Just try `#31#` from your mobile, no need to do a factory reset. Please don't trust that forwarded message and all.

Answer (score 0):

Dial #31# and call. After then it will start working outgoing calls.